# Link between electric potential energy formula and physical explanation

Tags: electrostatics, charge, potential-energy, coulombs-law

Assume we have a single positively charged particle in space: it creates an electrostatic
potential. From what i understand, if we have another positively charged particle,in order to
bring them very close to one another,one would have to use an infinite amount of energy, so the potential at the location of the first particle would be infinite.

The phenomenon that I described is reflected by the fact that the potential is proportional to the inverse of the distance between the two particles.

But what if one particle is positive and the other is negative? does the formula still hold?
Because we do not need an infinite amount of energy to bring two particles of contrary signs together...
Can someone explain to me what is going on there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose we had a fixed negative point charge, and a positive test charge very far away from it.  Suppose we then gave the positive test charge a small nudge, and it started moving towards the fixed negative charge.  It can be shown that (if these were truly point charges) the electric field of the negative charge would *do* an infinite amount of work on the test charge.

But the change in the potential energy associated with a conservative force is minus the amount of work done by that force, it must be that the potential energy of the positive test charge is $-\infty$ when it gets to the same location as the fixed negative charge.   This means that the electric potential at the location of the negative charge must also be $-\infty$, since the electric potential is the ratio of the potential energy of a positive test charge to the magnitude of that test charge.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to think about.

a) When the particles are infinitely far apart that is convenient to say the potential energy is zero since there is no interaction. However you don't have to make that assumption so you could assign another place for the potential energy to be zero. This is because it is a conservative field, and what you care about is the difference in potentials  when it comes to work being performed. In other words the integral of F dot dl (the work)is path independent and you just care about the starting final positions of the charges when finding the work performed (Energy). This also holds if you have unlike charges, or two charges of the same sign.

b) For particles like protons (and neutrons), as you bring them together, eventually you have the strong force that will keep them together. So you need to consider more than just the electrostatic repulsion. So one answer to your question is that you need to add more physics to your problem. Note that the range of the strong force is very short, so your coulmb formula is pretty good until you bring the two positive charges very close together.

[image: Strong +electrostatic force]